# Stylized E-Mail

Tags: php, email

I'm creating a registration form and when you submit it sends you a comfirmation email. I want my email to be more than just text.

I have no clue how to do this or where to start
I tried to search for this, I don't have the right keywords because nothing is coming up.
I tried to add html tags and style but it just came in as raw text.

Help?

```
$to      = 'user@gmail.com';
$subject = '2014 Comfirmation';
$message = "<h1>Test Header<h1>\r\n
<img src=\"http://www.image.com/_newSite/img/logo.jpg\"/>
<p style='border:solid thin red'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc malesuada dui a dictum blandit. Suspendisse commodo tincidunt diam. Duis orci tellus, imperdiet et vestibulum vitae, aliquet sit amet velit. Aenean a massa eu neque interdum viverra. Donec interdum arcu neque, ac egestas lectus mattis a. Duis nec dictum mauris. In eget facilisis nibh. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Aenean ac leo ut mauris aliquet gravida eget eu magna. Mauris ullamcorper sagittis risus, eu molestie mi iaculis eu. Proin ut elementum risus. Vivamus rhoncus ipsum elit, in ultrices quam elementum et.</p>

Line 2\r\n


Line 3


";

$headers = 'From: from@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: from@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

// In case any of our lines are larger than 70 characters, we should use wordwrap()
$message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");

// Send
@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php <-- Example #4

Comment: What's the problem with your keywords? http://goo.gl/klksg2

Comment: i didn't use the word "nice", i search stylized emails , thank you

Comment: Search for "HTML e-mail".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the correct `Content-type` in your email headers:

```
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
           'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n" .
           'Reply-To: fake@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
           'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

By default mail clients will treat mail as text, unless that mail explicitly specifies that it should be treated as HTML.  Now, making that HTML pretty is an entirely different matter.  Note also that HTML messages are more likely to be considered SPAM by filters.  As a general word of advice, don't go overboard with the styling.  Less is more.

Answer (score 0):

I personally recommend using a library such as PHPMailer for HTML emails because if you also want to do an email attachment then good luck with native `mail();` in PHP

On a side-note:

HTML emails are notoriously hard to get right because various mail services such as Yahoo and GMAIL have a parsing algorithm to remove potentially malicious code.

**GMAIL**

- CANNOT use internal style sheets
- Parsing can get caught up on random character and it will remove an entire inline style such as `padding-left:10px;`

**Yahoo**

- Internal style sheet supported but has great opportunity to get screwed up
- Parsing can get caught up on random character and it will remove an entire inline style such as `padding-left:10px;`

**Outlook**

- Seems to do just fine with style sheets and inline styles unless client has HTML emails disabled for security reasons